Memory Issue with Logfj Logger
I have a Spring boot webflux application which uses Log4j2 for logging. I am using latest version of Spring Boot starter 3.3.3 and its log4j2. When I did my performance test and its consuming lot of memory and causing major GC event.
When I took the HeapDump and exported to MAT it's ponting to 3 component as Leak suspects.
Log4jLoggerFactory -> 60.45 MB
Logger -> 9,82,392 (Objects) -> Occupies 119.92 MB
String -> 73.12 MB
I got this HeapDump stats after 10 hours of application run. But not been able to identify from where these Logger objects are getting created. When I open the reference tree in MAT its not saying any reference to application class most of the node are pointing to framework specific classes.
In this case how to approach this issue and how to identify why these many logger instance created and why its occupies this many memory?
My my application defined all the Logger as private final and all my application class is annotated with @Component. So Ideally only one instance of Logger should be created per class.

Just some clarifications... This memory leak occurrs with any logging level? Are the class logger instances defined also as static, other than private final?

Do you have 982 392 Logger instances or objects retained by Log4jLoggerFactory? Log4j Core has by default a high memory footprint in exchange for no or limited GC collections. See Garbage-free logging on how to tune that.

@FrancescoPoli Logger is defined with private final only but all my class are defined with spring Component so ideally one instance of the class will be created. So each class should have only one Logger as per my understanding. Please correct me if i am wrong. Also Im not sure is it expected to have these many instance of Logger on peak load?

@PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for the reference. Yes when took the HeapDump during high memory usage I could see 982 392 Logger object listed and its retaining around 20 MB of space.

@springbootlearner you're right on @Component instances, if they have no other scope than the default (singleton) or if in tests you are creating them directly and not getting them through application context. The static modifier might be superfluous in general, but I would try using it to see if memory occupancy decreases anyway.
